# Journald not logging custom fields on debian

Tags: debian, logging, systemd

I have the following script that I run on both an Arch Linux machine as well as a Debian stretch machine. On the Arch Linux machine I'm able to find the random value that was logged, whereas I can't seem to retrieve it on the Debian machine.

Anyone know if I need to configure something in Debian differently? Or if this is just because I'm running an older version of `systemd` on Debian?

```
import logging
import random

from systemd.journal import JournalHandler

LOGGER = logging.getLogger("this_is_a_logger")
JOURNAL_HANDLER = JournalHandler()

JOURNAL_HANDLER.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))

# add the journald handler to the current logger
LOGGER.addHandler(JOURNAL_HANDLER)

# optionally set the logging level
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

LOGGER.info(
    "test log event to systemd!",
    extra={"RANDOM_NUMBER": random.randint(0, 10), "LEVEL": "INFO"},
)
```

The command I'm using to check if the random number was logged is:

```
journalctl  -S "10 minutes ago" \
            LOGGER="this_is_a_logger" \
            -o json-pretty \
            | jq -r  ".RANDOM_NUMBER"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You're using an outdated version of *python-systemd*; Debian stable has v233 while support for the logger adapter's `extra=` parameter was only added [in version v234](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/commit/308ae4440c1f6ea1aff9be4cb683c52bd3a1c13a).

If you cannot upgrade the python module, use the 'raw' `systemd.journal.send()` API.